# Add string_array within Restsharp.AddParameter and .AddJsonBody

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am currently encountering difficulties in adding a `string array` into an `POST` request defined via `Restsharp`, and hope to obtain a feedback in relation to the adequate syntax:

***Using request.AddParameter***

```
var request = new RestRequest("/xxxx", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddParameter("body_text", "[segment1, segment2, segment3]");
```

where the targeted `string_array = [segment1, segment2, segment3]`

***Using request.AddJsonBody***

```
request.AddJsonBody(new
        {
            version = "",
            body_text = "[segment1, segment2, segment3]"
        });
```

Idem: `string_array = [segment1, segment2, segment3]`

Thanks in advance